# Helm: coalesce.go:196: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for env (map[])

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When I run `helm install myproject ./myproject --namespace mynamespace`, I always receive these warnings, even when I remove all my templates.

```
coalesce.go:196: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for env (map[])
coalesce.go:196: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for env (map[])
coalesce.go:196: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for env (map[])
NAME: myproject
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Jan 28 17:48:30 2020
NAMESPACE: mynamespace
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
```

My versions:

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.7", GitCommit:"6c143d35bb11d74970e7bc0b6c45b6bfdffc0bd4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-11T12:34:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.2", GitCommit:"19e47ee3283ae98139d98460de796c1be1e3975f", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.5"}
```

What could they mean?

Comment: I found additional information here: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7902.
However, I see the same warning with Helm Version `3.4.2`.

Comment: I don't have the pb anymore, but if I quote well your link "If you do filters: {}, I believe that warning would go away". I think you could write an answer with it :)

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you provided the helm chart, but I am guessing you might have a helm chart where the default `env` is not listed as a list.

Meaning, the helm chart with no env should have the following:

```
env: []
```

you would run into the above error if for example, you had `env: {}` instead.